# Group by in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have 3 columns in a Pandas dataframe. I want to group by col1 and col2 while aggregating on col1 and col3. I am using the following code -

```
df.groupby(["col1","col2"]).agg({"col3": "count","col1":"sum"}).reset_index()
```

I get the following error -

```
cannot insert col1, already exists
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: kindly provide sample dataframe and expected output. From face value I dont think you can groupby and aggregate on the same column

Comment: I understand the error is because of reset.index(). It is assigning the same name to 2 columns. Any work around to that?

Comment: ``df.groupby(["col1","col2"], as_index = False).agg({"col3": "count","col1":"sum"})`` maybe? if not, kindly share sample dataframe and expected output

Comment: temporarily rename col1 after aggregation, do reset_index, drop col1, and then rename temp one back?

Comment: Can you please tell how can I rename at the same time as grouping it?

Comment: @tester559v I've answered your query. Check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its throwing error because of duplication of column names while reseting index. 
First rename the columns you aggregated then `reset_index()`.

```
df.groupby(["col1","col2"]).agg({"col3":"count","col1":"sum"}).rename(columns={'col1':'col1_count',"col3":"col3_count"}).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily rename `col1` after aggregation, do `reset_index`, drop original `col1`, and then rename temp one back:

```
df.groupby(["col1","col2"]).agg({"col3":"count", "col1":"sum"})\
                            .rename(columns={'col1':'col1_temp'})\
                            .reset_index().drop('col1', axis=1)\
                            .rename(columns={'col1_temp':'col1'})
```